# Geting error for xpath written using parent-child traverse

Tags: xpath

I have tried to write a xpath using parent-child traverse for the login button on the main GitHub Page(https://github.com/) and on the main salesforce page(https://www.salesforce.com/in/?ir=1), but its not working. Could anybody find the mistake I have made in the xpath in the code below?
[Code for login using parent-child traverse xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ReY2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the login button on saleforce homepage you can use :

```
//div[contains(@class,"flydown")]
```

or replace [5] with [6] in your XPath expression :

```
//div[@class="inner"]//div[6]/div/div/a
```

For GitHub, use :

```
//a[contains(@data-ga-click,"sign-in")]
```